# C# checked block

Tags: c#, checked

Can someone explain to me what exactly is the **checked** an **unchecked** block ?
And when should I use each ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Arithmetic overflow; for example:

```
int i = int.MaxValue -10;
checked {       
   i+= 20; // boom: OverflowException
           // "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."
}
```

So use `checked` when you don't want ***accidental*** overflow / wrap-around to be a problem, and would rather see an exception.

`unchecked` explicitly sets the mode to allow overflow; the default is `unchecked` unless you tell the compiler otherwise - either through code (above) or a compiler switch (`/checked` in csc).

Comment: This is old but couldn't we just use a try/catch instead? Just trying to figure out use case scenario.

Comment: @Si8 nope; the entire point here is to **cause** an error; by default c# uses unchecked arithmetic, so overflows happen silently. Adding a try/catch won't do anything if it never throws. It is adding the `checked`  that *makes it throw* on overflow

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 13):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> C# statements can execute in either
>   checked or unchecked context. In a
>   checked context, arithmetic overflow
>   raises an exception. In an unchecked
>   context, arithmetic overflow is
>   ignored and the result is truncated.

In short, they are used to define the context in which the arithmetic operations take place. In the checked context an exception is thrown when overflow happens. In an unchecked context an exception is not thrown and the value is wrapped-around instead.

Now, whether your context is unchecked or checked depends on your compiler options. So if you want to manually override the context, i.e perform a checked operation in an otherwise unchecked context or vice-versa, you should use these keywords.

For more details and examples follow the link given above.

Comment: unchecked blocks are good from when you want overflow to just wrap around, like when calculating a hashcode.

Answer (score 7):

> checked blocks use to handle arithmetic overflow/underflow situations. 
>   For a example:

Let's say you want to convert  an int value into a short type value (called a narrowing conversion). int type variable can have value range from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. But short can have only from -32,768 to 32,767.

Due to that reason short variable can not have all possible values that an int variable can have. If some how, one may cast as following example:

```
                int y = 1000000000;
                short x = (short)y;
```

Clearly you can see value of y is in outside the valid values for a short variable. So arithmetic overflow situation take place.

By default C# doesn't throw any exception for above code. But there are few ways you can throw an exception and handle it. In that case checked blocks comes in handy

```
        try
        {
            checked
            {
                int y = 1000000000;
                short x = (short)y;
            }
        }
        catch (OverflowException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hey, we got a overflow/underflow situation");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
```

catch block caused throwing an overflow exception,if casting caused an overflow/underflow situation.
In this case it shows the error message

> "hey, we got a overflow/underflow situation"
>
> unchecked blocks are use if we want to discard the underflow/overflow when a conversion happened and continue the operation.